# Auto-archiving data in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm fairly new to apps script and writing script entirely, however, I've dabbled a bit. For a little bit of context on my ask, my team meets weekly and use a google sheet to manage department updates. I'd like to have this sheet archived so that we can clear each week.

Problem: I want to copy a sheet into another workbook weekly. The intent is to create an archive.

```
function cloneGoogleSheet(ssA, ssB) {
   // source doc
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('10ui5vIJkE0z-DVZ8ywJPLscrhZ84u5SSBchUN-BsbE0');

  // source sheet
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('NEW Department Updates');

  // Get full range of data
  var SRange = ss.getDataRange();

  // get A1 notation identifying the range
  var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();

  // get the data values in range
  var SData = SRange.getValues();

  // target spreadsheet
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1TP6HqfZSLAKLco2hTfyrsCzYUW76KY0zEZDzoaeI7CA');

  // target sheet
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Department Updates'); 

  // Clear the Google Sheet before copy
  //ts.clear({contentsOnly: true});

  // set the target range to the values of the source data
  ts.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData);

};
```

Request: How can I add in language around appending rows? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is maybe a quicker way to do it if it's what your looking for

```
var ssA = SpreadsheetApp.openById('10ui5vIJkE0z-DVZ8ywJPLscrhZ84u5SSBchUN-BsbE0');
var sheetA = ssA.getSheetByName('NEW Department Updates');
var dataToMove = sheetA.getRange(1,1,sheetA.getLastRow(),sheetA.getLastColumn()).getValues();
var ssB = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1TP6HqfZSLAKLco2hTfyrsCzYUW76KY0zEZDzoaeI7CA'); 
var sheetB = ssB.getSheetByName('Department Updates');
dataToMove.forEach(function(elts){
sheetB.appendRow(elts)
});

sheetA.deleteRows(1,sheetA.getLastRow());
```

I hope I've answered at what you're looking for .

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!!